# How to extract the value of an element in a period of time data in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm sorry if the title didn't match with my explanation. But here's my problem:

I have data about uber request for 2 weeks each hour. I want to know which hour of the day I had the most request for 2 weeks period. The data looks like this:

```
Date     Time     request
12/1/16   0          2
          1          1
          2          3
          ..         ..
          ..         ..
          23         6
12/2/16   0          4
          1          2
          2          5              
          ..         ..
          ..         ..
          23         6
```

and it goes on until 2 weeks. I want to know which hour of the day I had the most request. Any idea how I do this?

Comment: Select the two right two columns (time and request), and create a Pivot table from them. It will show you the hours from 0 to 23 and the totaled counts for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Aganju says,

Create a pivot table by selecting the two Columns (Time & Request), in the Pivot Table Window use "Time" as RowLabels & "Request" as Values, change the value settings to "Sum".